# Bitbucket Pipeline Laravel with MySQL php_network_getaddresses

Tags: laravel, docker, pdo, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I use php7.2-fpm-stretch docker image and MySQL as an attached service. Following command runs successfully:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u username -ppassword
```

However, when composer wants to run `package:discover` it ends up with the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

The `.env` file has the following configuration for the database:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_CONNECTION=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=pipeline
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

And my yml file is as below:

```
image: php:7.2-fpm-stretch

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -qy git unzip mysql-client
          #Some other non-related configuration
          - composer install
          - php artisan key:generate
        services:
          - mysql
definitions:
  services:
    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'pipeline'
        MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        MYSQL_USER: 'username'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
```

Comment: Not know bitbucket pipeline, but 2 images I guess finally will start 2 containers, how could `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` could work for connection from one container to another container as they are totally 2 instances? Just a guess. Unless the bitbucket pipeline have magic to combine 2 images to 1 container... Then it's really magic!

Comment: Er, maybe it could define some network just like k8s pod, like containers in a Pod run on a “logical host”; they use the same network namespace (in other words, the same IP address and port space). Forget this if bitbucket pipeline also did this...

Comment: Yes, because bitbucket itself has documentation where it refers to use 127.0.0.1 to access to the mysql attached service

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes, forgot to post an answer. You should make sure that your bitbucket pipeline env variable and your .env file variables have different names. Let me know if it helped you so, I post it as an answer for others. rename your bitbucket env variables if they have the same name as .env variables.

Comment: @HosseinShahsahebi would you be able to share a bit more? What do you mean by different names in .env ? Are you talking about the database values? Could you provide an example please? My connection is trying to access: `mysql://test_user:test_user_password@127.0.0.1:3306/pipelines`

Comment: @victorkurauchi, values do not matter. If you're writing your query string just like this, it wouldn't have anything to do with bitbucket env variables. But, if you're reading `test_user` and `test_user_password` from your app's env file, make sure those keys do not have a conflict with the env variables you've defined in bitbucket.